# Get stock_data from Magento API get request

Tags: api, magento

I know I can get stock data when making a request for an individual product:

`http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:id`

But please tell me there is a way to get stock_data when requesting a list:

`http://magentohost/api/rest/products`

I'm trying to do large imports (>10k products) that include all this data, and doing it one-by-one is way too slow.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I think Soap Api would be great Pls refer here http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.list.html

Comment: I'm using rest, so that won't work.

Comment: http://magentohost/api/rest/stockitems I have seen the wiki of rest and it says that it will provide the list

Comment: @chanz I just saw that too.. it works! You should post it as an answer.

Comment: thanks my suggestion was helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://magentohost/api/rest/stockitems
```

provides the list of product with stock inventory details for REST API.

Comment: Works perfect. Too bad I need to make 2x the requests on in the initial import, but at least I don't have to import products one at a time! Thanks a lot chanz!

Comment: I get the error ```Request does not match any route```, did the url change after magento v2 ?